# how to change supportsRtl value inside the app

Tags: android

as i know if we set android:supportsRtl="true" in manifest the app will change it's direction based on default language of the phone ..my problem is that lot's of people in my country set their default language to English whereas they know a little about English an if they open app and see the application language is English they will definetly remove the app .. so my question is is there any way to change the value inside the app . and i give them the option to change language at the beggening of the app or in setting .. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below code to set language for app, this is for english, replace the `en` with you language:

```
         Locale locale = new Locale("en"); 
         Locale.setDefault(locale);
         Configuration config = new Configuration();
         config.locale = locale;
         getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

in manifest file write `android:configChanges="locale"`.

You can give them to choose language at any time, but remember all activities language are change except current activity, you have to restart current activity.

Comment: ty @asif patel so it dose not change the language of phone ? or dose it require any premission ?

Comment: it does not change your phone language, it change your app language and not require any permissions.